# accessing objects from a class

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I have created a seperate .cs file names aNameClass.cs and have stored the following class in it.
I am able to iniatiate it in my Main() statment, but when I try to access the GetChoice object, it tells me it is inaccesable due to invalid prividlidges.

here is my code to iniatiate it and access it.

```
namespace aNameCollector
{
// ...

csGetChoice gc = new csGetChoice();
choice = gc.GetChoice();   //invalid prividlidges???


    class csGetChoice
    {
        static string GetChoice()
        {
            string choice = " ";
            Console.WriteLine("++++++++++++++++++=A Name Collector+++++++++++++++");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("E = Enter a Name || D = Delete a Name || C = Clear Collector || V = View Collector || Q = Quit");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();
          return choice;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a static reference and specify `public` for the method like this:

```
// static access:
choice = csGetChoice.GetChoice(); 
...
public static string GetChoice() { ...
```

or make the method an instance method instead of static and define and access it like this:

```
// instance access:
csGetChoice gc = new csGetChoice();
choice = gc.GetChoice();  
...
public string GetChoice() { ... // static keyword removed
```

If you don't provide an [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the default is `private` and therefore visible only to the class that contains it and not to any other classes.

Comment: now it says that it can not be accessed with an instance reference, quailfy it with a type name instead? What does that mean?

Comment: Actually all I have to do is call the full class name, then my object becomes visible. thanks.

Comment: For me to create an instance was wrong, for me to call the class, then object was right.

Comment: @jpalov:Yes right,Static mehtod works on type not on the instance

Comment: Sorry, I missed that issue the first time around. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make the method **public**  and call the static method on type not on the instance

```
csGetChoice.GetChoice();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `static` key word for a **type member** states that you can access it by referencing the `class` directly and not its **objects**. However, you still need the right access modifier to be able to access that **member**.

`private` is the default value when you don't **explicitly** declare the access modifier in **C#** as in your case. And that allows you to access that **member** only inside its `class`.

To be able to access it from outside the `class` you need to **explicitly** use other **access modifiers** as `public`.